# How can I find Time complexity for "while loop" and "power statement"

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the time complexity of two python statements:

1. while loops: I understand how to find the complexity class of for loops, but when it comes to while loops the case is completely different how can I stop here? the condition controls the loop...
2. power statement: is the time complexity affected by the pow function?

Here is an example of a program statement:

```
  Upper=100
  n =random.randrange(0, Upper)
  while gcd(n, Upper) != 1:
      n = random. randrange(0, Upper)  # question 1

  

  pow(c, n - 1, n)  # (c ^n-1 mod n)   question 2
                    #where n is a large prime number
```

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of the while loop is the number of iterations times the complexities of the loop test plus loop body. (More generally, in case these complexities vary from iteration to iteration, you must consider the sum of the complexities across iterations.)

For the pow function, there is no single answer. Using a fixed-length representation, you may assume O(1) complexity, though is some contexts it could be O(log e) where e is the exponent.

Comment: Thanks very much for your attention, but the while loop can not limit by size? the loop is depending on the generated number, if it catches the condition it will be stopped. How can I calculate the time complexity here?